# Use of specialised lexis in novels

Tags: word-choice

Ben Marcus in *Watching misteries with my mother* writes:

She will have spent her entire life having no control whatsoever of what happens inside her **body**, with her **blood** and **cells** and **bones**, not to mention the **organs** and **nerves**, and now, 86 years into this seasoned indifference [...]

What does the use of these "tecnical" lexical items imply? 
The short short has nothing to do with the medical field and this is the only sentence with words regarding this semantic field.
Has the writer used this lexis to create a certain ambiance?

Thank you

Comment: These aren't particularly technical terms. They're just body parts. But of course as you already know using words from a somewhat narrow domain makes you think of that domain. You've already answered your own question.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that the author is attempting to emphasize the distinct separation of the character's body and mind by describing the body's constituent parts in a fairly mechanical/functional way. (Compare this to how the meaning would change if the author had talked about the character's heart, which is often used metaphorically.) This helps to emphasize the character's "seasoned indifference" to her body.